Get data from html form to Google sheet
I have a simple web for users submitting data from HTML form to Google sheet for my company like this repo  https://github.com/levinunnink/html-form-to-google-sheet
But when I config the app. My web app can only be used by anyone in my company so when I submit data the API response 401.
I want to know if there is any way for the users to submit data to our company's google sheet or any keyword to search about this.

Based on your shared information, you are following the same repo provided? I can see that from the Repo it is not using any API, can you share how you fetch the API also the platform you are using because depending on this information answers may vary. Please include a copy of what you currently have, tried and specific issue you are experiencing.

Web app → Who has access: Anyone. If that option isn't available, contact your admin.
